# Is "Notices of the American Mathematical Society" available before 1995?

Tags: journals

I tried to find some paper published in Notices of the American Mathematical Society 1975

By E. Calabi, On manifolds with non-negative Ricci curvature II 

Notices of the American Mathematical Society 22 1975 A205

But when I searched at mathscinet and click Calabi, there is no such a paper listed under his name.

Also AMS's website does not have any issues from before 1995. So is it a book or something?

Comment: The earliest Notices entry I was able to get from MathSciNet was 1983. I'm not quite sure why.

Comment: Long ago, the Notices of the AMS published essentially just meeting announcements and abstracts of talks.  The Calabi citation seems to be well within this "long ago", so it is probably just an announcement of results, not a real paper.  

Comment: @Andreas Blass, I see, thank you. That's probably the reason why no actual pages was referred in the paper.

Comment: As Andreas points out, the *Notices* has evolved from being just a formal record of meetings (with abstracts), elections, etc.  Among the abstracts published were quite a few that didn't correspond to talks actually given at meetings and that may or may not show up in published work later on.   At that time the *Bulletin* published more detailed multi-page research announcements, but these too didn't always have follow-up.

Comment: Yes, that "A" part of the number means it is the listing of an abstract.  

Comment: There wasn't room in the margins for the proofs.

Comment: The full January 1975 issue is [here](http://ams.org/journals/notices/197501/197501FullIssue.pdf), thanks to Michael Greinecker's answer.  A-205 actually is the page number (abstracts were in a separate section with page numbers A-xxx).  Calabi's abstract is number 720-53-6.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As Andreas Blass and others surmised, this is indeed an abstract.  It was for a 10-minute talk at the Annual Meeting in January, 1975.  Here is the entire "paper":

> **On Manifolds with nonnegative Ricci curvature II**
>
> Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional
>   Riemannian manifold with nonnegative
>   Ricci curvature.  Then the exponential
>   mapping $\exp_p$ for any $p\in M$ ,
>   restricted to the domain bounded by
>   the cut locus, is everywhere volume
>   decreasing.From this fact one deduces
>   the following THEOREM.  Let $M$ be a
>   Riemannian, $n$-dimensional, complete
>   manifold with nonnegative Ricci
>   curvature.  Then, if $r$ denotes the
>   injectivity radius and $D$ the
>   geodesic diameter of $M$ , the volume
>   $V$ of $M$ satisfies $V \ge c_nr^{n-1}D$, where $c_n$ is a positive
>   constant depending on $n$ .  In
>   particular, if $M$ is not compact (i.
>   e. if $D=\infty$), the volume of $M$ ,
>   under the same assumptions, is
>   infinite. (Received November 6, 1974.)

A couple of notes.  I reproduced the capitalization and (non)hyphenation of the title as it appeared in the *Notices*.  I also tried to preserve some oddities in punctuation in the text, but otherwise "TeX-ified" it; the original is literally typed, with a handwritten $\in$ symbol.

**Added 11/13/12:** Out of idle curiosity, I went back to the library today, to see if Calabi ever gave a talk titled "On Manifolds with nonnegative Ricci curvature I."  If he did, it wasn't at an AMS meeting (or else I didn't dig back far enough).

In the process, however, I noticed that, beginning in October, 1972, the *Notices* ran a "Queries" column, inviting "questions from members regarding mathematical matters such as details of, or references to, vaguely remembered theorems, sources of exposition of folk theorems, or the state of current knowledge concerning published conjectures" -- i.e., a sort of snail-mail version of MathOverflow.  Here's the inaugural query (the answer to which arrived in a then-speedy three months):

> 1 . R.P. Boas (2440 Simpson Street, Evanston, Illinois 60201).  Given a
>   finite collection of vectors, of total
>   length 1, in a plane, we can always
>   arrange them in a polygon, starting
>   from 0, that at some stage gets at
>   least $1/\pi$ away from 0.  Mitrinovic
>   [*Analytic inequalities*, 1970, pp.
>   331-332] cites Bourbaki [1955], but
>   the theorem was known at least in the
>   early 1940's, when I remember seeing a
>   paper on it; can anybody supply the
>   reference?

My own favorite is from the next issue:

> 4 . Cleve B. Moler (Department of Mathematics, University of New Mexico,
>   Albuquerque, New Mexico 87106).  Can
>   somebody recommend a good source where
>   I can learn about the connection of
>   mathematics and various biological
>   processes such as photosynthesis?

Cleve Moler is perhaps best known as the inventor of MATLAB.

In conclusion, the answer to the OP's question, "is the *Notices* available before 1995?" the answer seems to be yes, but only at libraries that hold onto old journals.  I wonder if the AMS could be persuaded to make the early volumes of the *Notices* available through JSTOR.

Comment: This result was proved almost at the same time by Yau, his proof appeared here http://www.iumj.indiana.edu/docs/25051/25051.asp (Theorem 7).

Comment: @YangMills, I knew Yau's proof and was trying to find what was the "other method" that Calabi had in his mind. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Barry: My personal copies have long sincd been recycled, but intrepid people can actually find these back issues locally.   Not in the UMass library (or nearby small college libraries), but under a nearby mountain in the Five College Depository.   This was built by the feds during the Cold War to house bank documents in case of nuclear war, but is now owned by Amherst College.   Old journals buried there can be requested, I guess, but the location was more useful during filming of a Mel Gibson thriller a few years ago.   

Comment: @Jim, great comment!  I actually found the *Notices* here yesterday in the periodicals section of the stacks in the math library at the University of Minnesota and today in the bowels of Rolvaag Library at St. Olaf College.

Comment: @J.GE, From the abstract, it is not clear what is Calabi's proof, but probably it has the same flavor as this one: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/77558/area-of-distance-sphere-in-manifold-with-ricci-ge-0/139624#139624

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, thank you, the spurious symbol was caused by a line break in the block quoting, which puts a "greater than" symbol at the front of each line.

Answer (score 10):

To update the answer in the title question: Full issues of the Notices of the AMS from 1954 onwards are now available online. Just follow [this link](http://ams.org/cgi-bin/notices/amsnotices.pl?article_id=fullissue&article_type=gallery&gallery_type=fullissue) and click on "Full Issues Browsing Options and Other Notices Collections."