# series of special articles of Notices AMS

Tags: reference-request, ho.history-overview, journals

Notices AMS  used to publish series of Special Articles devoted to exposition of extraordinary quality.

some of the articles include:

***Local algebraic topology***   by Frank Quinn

***Rademacher on J(τ), Poincaré series of nonpositive weights and the Eichler cohomology***.  by  Marvin Knopp

Does anybody know where i could find a full list of the titles of the articles in this series.

Comment: If you have MathSciNet, [this search](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?batch_title=Selected+Matches+for%3A+Journal%3D%28Notices+Amer.+Math.+Soc.%29&pg7=REFF&s8=All&yrop=eq&pg4=TI&s6=Notices+Amer.+Math.+Soc.&s5=&pg5=AUCN&pg6=JOUR&s4=&dr=all&arg3=&pg8=ET&yearRangeFirst=&s7=&review_format=html&yearRangeSecond=&fmt=doc&sort=oldest&searchin=) likely produces a superset...

Answer (score 1):

Here http://www.ams.org/publications/notices/whatis/noticesarchive you can find a list of short "What is" type AMS notices articles. At the same page you can select an year and month and look for the corresponding issue's table of contents. For a list of other journals which publish expository papers, see the answers to this MO question [Which journals publish expository work?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15366/which-journals-publish-expository-work)

Comment: Unlike MathSciNet, this currently only covers 1995-present — so won't reveal articles like the OP's sample two (1986, 1990).

Comment: Yes, i have just noticed that it only covers 1995-present. Unfortunately, I do not have MathSciNet. It seems  before 1995 the Notices of the AMS published essentially just meeting announcements and abstracts: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/112231/is-notices-of-the-american-mathematical-society-available-before-1995/112247